# css selector :not with this structure doen't work in my case

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customize the font size for the label text but in the meanwhile I need that the font-size affects only the text and not the checkbox button. This is my code:

```css
    .check-field-privacy:not(.Form-fieldIcon) {
     font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<label class="check-field-privacy Form-label Form-label--block" for="checkprivacybox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="Form-input" id="checkprivacybox" aria-required="true" required="">
     <span class="Form-fieldIcon" role="presentation"></span> Privacy Policy
    </label>
```

But it seems not working for some reason. The checkbox is affected itself by this rule.

What's wrong and how can I write a rule to set the size of the font only for the label but excluding the  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `label` doesn't have the `Form-fieldIcon` class.

Comment: It's not working because you are using it wrong - the not means that the first selector does not include the second selector - it doesn't mean that the first selector does not contain a child element with the second selector.  There is currently no css to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can directly target the span element

```
.check-field-privacy span{
  font-size:12px;
}
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: I want the opposite of what you suggested: only the <span class="Form-fieldIcon" role="presentation"></span> shouldn't have font-size: 12px

Comment: do you want the checkbox size to be increased?

Comment: or the text which is in the span should be affected?

Comment: @Francesco just set the font size for the span separately then

Comment: I don't want to set the font size of the span separately. I want to leave it as is (2em) but not affecting it size with the css rule on the label. Is it possible?

Comment: That is not possible, every element inherits it’s parents css unless overridden. So your label tag has a css defined, unless u override your span tag with different css it will inherit properties from label tag.